# Django 2.0 error in urls.py relating to views.py

Tags: django, url, view

Edit:This was NOT an exact duplicate of a previous question. I just solved the problem WITHOUT using  as suggested in the so called duplicate answer- so what was suggested was wrong/unnecessary. In fact the problem arose, because I was trying to use  when it was not needed.

I have the following code that seeks to load a page localhost/music/1 ...I have been following a tutorial that uses Django 1.9.

**The code that is throwing up the error is:**

**music/urls.py**

```
# this is matching /music/1 where 1 is the album id
path('(?P<album_id>)[0-9]+)/', views.detail, name='detail'), #note album_id is the variable being stored which can be passed
```

**music/views.py**

```
def detail(request,album_id):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Details for Album id:" + str(album_id) + "</h2>")
```

**The error message:**

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/2
Using the URLconf defined in website.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
music/ [name='index']
music/ (?P<album_id>)[0-9]+)/ [name='detail']
videos/
The current path, music/2, didn't match any of these.
```

Can anyone post a fix/answer that will solve the problem.

Thanks

Comment: there should be a slash at the end of `music/2/`

Comment: How do I incorporate that into the equation ....does the / I have now need to be put inside the brackets?

Comment: I **literally** told you what to do a week ago when you asked a question on precisely the same subject. I don't understand how you can be having exactly the same problem again.

Comment: This was NOT an exact duplicate. I just solved the problem WITHOUT USING <int> - so what you had suggested was in fact wrong.

Comment: use this `path('<album_id>',views.detail, name='detail')`

Answer (score -1):

You have an extra parenthesis ")"

```
path('(?P<album_id>)[0-9]+)/'
                   ^
```

It should be

```
path('(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/'
```

But in any case, if you're usin django 2.0, [check how to use path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/), it doesn't use those regex codes anymore.

**EDIT**

As per @Daniel Roseman answer, `path` shouldn't be used with regex, in spite of the parenthesis typo.

Comment: What regex codes are you referring to?

Comment: I also tried this for Django 2.0 - but it didn't work either: path("<album_id">/",views.detail,name="detail")

Comment: `(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)` is a regex code, in django 2.0  path you use `/<int:album_id>/`

Comment: And for the first, I tried this: path('(?p<album_id>)[0-9]+/)', views.detail, name='detail'), ....still no luck. Will try your suggestion above in a sec

Comment: I tried this: but didn't work - path('(int:<album_id>)[0-9]+/)', views.detail, name='detail'),